# Excluding a set of characters in encryption / decryption

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption

I'm facing few issues after encryption and decryption is done. I'm trying to encrypt / decrypt my query string (not the host name and context) using JAVA Crypt API. We never know what sort of string we are going to get. Well, this is happening properly. Once this encryption is done, I need to pass this URL to a JS function where this is getting failed throwing **Unterminated String Constant**. The problem here is with the `/` character and, etc.

Also, few other characters because of which the initial encryption is not happening. **Ex: +**

Also I see few line breaks in the encrypted string. Why this line break? Is it part of encryption? Now I want to figure out the characters which are creating this problem and I'd like to tell the encrypter algorithm that not to use these set of characters. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: This looks like a strange and insecure way of protecting a database by encrypting the queries. If the number of queries is fix you should encode them on server side in a ASP/PHP/JSP... code and never send it to the client!

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Java and the Crypt API but it seems to me that you are having an issue of **encoding**. Since the output of the encryption is binary it is probable that the API encodes it, and it looks like you get `base64` encoding by default. So I'd look in the API spec to see how to change/set the encoding and used a different encoding e.g. hex.

You can test the assumption by taking the encrypted output of your API and passing it through a base64 decoder, either the linux `base64` tool or an online decoder.

Comment: After a couple of runs, I found that this is happening because of the line breaks. From this [ref](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp), I saw there is an option named *Max characters per line* Why to limit no. of characters per line?

Comment: I guess because base64 is heavily used in protocols like SMTP where number of chars per line is limited

Comment: Anyway I can avoid this? How to tell the API that don't restrict the characters per line?

Comment: I am not familiar with this API. I'd look up how to set and configure the encoding used by it. It could be easier to change the encoding to something more suitable

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass this URL to a JS function where this is getting failed
>   throwing Unterminated String Constant

It sounds to me like you actually need to escape this string for use in Javascript. e.g. see Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavascript()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29).

I doubt very much that you can control encryption character-by-character. It'll be dependent upon the algorithsm used, but will likely generate blocks of data from looking at chunks of data. It is encryption, after all.

Comment: I'm in a state where 'm supposed to write this encryption logic only. The converted url can be passed to a JS function or can be used as part of `href` etc. Bottom line is, the encrypted url (querystring) should fit at all places.

Comment: Indeed. You would need to escape it differently for XML, for Javascript etc. So you need to escape appropriately for the destination (in this case, Javascript)